# How to activate custom java rules during SonarQube analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I implemented custom rules for java as described here [enter link description here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules). Rules are visible on the server side at rules page, but no one from them is applied to code during analysis.
I'm using sonar 5.1.1 and updated sonar-java-plugin to v3.2. 
I'm wonder what's wrong. During debug using sonar-runner I noticed that my CheckRegistrar is loaded but checks from it is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple...Rules have to be included in Quality Profile.......